# Kerberos Upgrade

Tags: apache, hadoop, kerberos

We would like to upgrade Kerberos (both server and client)

- Current : 1.6.3-133.27.1
- Target : 1.6.3-133.49.97.1

Question is if we upgrade it with the package manager, what would happen to the following?

- KDC database
- All principal information
- All previously generated keytabs
- Kerberos configuration

Would all be working as before or everything has to be reconfigured?

The steps provided here for upgrade http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-1.4/krb5-1.4.4/doc/krb5-install/Upgrading-Existing-Kerberos-V5-Installations.html is for when we upgrade MAJOR version (1.1 to 1.2.x for example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Kerberos upgrade to server and client is not going to change the contents of the KDC database, characteristics of principals, will not affect previously generated keytabs or Kerberos configuration.  An example of this is Active Directory, when you upgrade AD versions authentication still occurs seamlessly.  If you think about this carefully, consider that if the key security elements you mentioned were to change during upgrades, nobody would upgrade.  :-)